# why does pool imap_unordered not work where map does in this case?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

It is my understanding that imap_unordered and map should be interchangeable, if you don't care about the order of outputs.  I've had this happen a few times now though, imap_unordered just doesn't work at all. I normally use with partial but here have switched to a tuple . Any help appreciated. Python 3.11.2

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial

def main ():
    query_seqs = list(range(22))
    print(len(query_seqs))
    with Pool(processes=7) as pool:
        tmp = [('args2', 'blast_type2', query) for query in query_seqs]
        pool.map(pool_tasks, tmp)
    print(len(query_seqs))
    with Pool(processes=7) as pool:
        tmp = [('args1', 'blast_type1', query) for query in query_seqs]
        pool.imap_unordered(pool_tasks, tmp)
    print(len(query_seqs))
def pool_tasks(tup):
    args, blast_type, query = tup
    print('args, blast_type, query', args, blast_type, query)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm *guessing* your problem is that you don't see any output of the form

```
args, blast_type, query args1 blast_type1 0
```

which causes you to believe that the unordered version "just doesn't work at all". Right?

But it does. You're letting that part of the code destroy the pool before any of the unordered tasks can run. Change this:

```py
        pool.imap_unordered(pool_tasks, tmp)
```

to, for example, this:

```py
        for x in pool.imap_unordered(pool_tasks, tmp):
            pass
```

Then the code won't fall off the end of the `with Pool` block before the unordered work completes.

In contrast, the ordered version constructs a list of the results, which is created regardless of whether you bind that list to a name. It stays in its `with Pool` block until the work is complete.

But the unordered version doesn't construct a list. It returns an iterator immediately and moves on.

Comment: Thanks! And sorry for having to guess, I had my kid literally pulling me away from my keyboard

Answer (score 3):

`Pool.map` blocks further progress in the main function, while `Pool.imap_unordered` does not. When the un-blocked process tries to leave the `with` statement's body, the pool shuts down, even if there is still work to be done.

You can get the same results with both, if you iterate over the value returned by `imap_unordered` and only exit when the iteration is done.

```
with Pool(processes=7) as pool:
    tmp = [('args1', 'blast_type1', query) for query in query_seqs]
    for result in pool.imap_unordered(pool_tasks, tmp):
        pass # or do something with result, if pool_tasks returns a value
```